Apple Sign In is telling me the given provider isn't enabled but it is
Trying to add Sign In With Apple support to a web app. It works using the firebase emulator suite but when using real firebase I'm getting the following error from signInWithPopup() even though I have sign in with Apple enabled in the firebase console.

FirebaseError: Firebase: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. (auth/operation-not-allowed).

async signInWithAppleHandler() {
     console.log('sign in with apple')
     var provider = new fb.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');
     provider.addScope('email');
     provider.addScope('name');
     await firebaseInstance.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
   }


If you're sure you've followed all of the instructions correctly, you should reach out to Firebase support directly for assistance. The error message is pretty clear, but if you're saying it's not telling you the right thing, then the volunteers of Stack Overflow will not be of help.
